# Python multiprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, multiprocess

I'm getting "EOFError: EOF when reading a line", when I try to take input.

```
def one():
    xyz = input("enter : ")
    print(xyz)

    time.sleep(1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Process
    import time

    p1 = Process(target = one)
    p1.start()
```

Comment: your process doesn't own stdin. The main process does. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: what is this stdin?

Comment: standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main process owns standard input, the forked process doesn't.

What would work would be to use `multiprocessing.dummy` which doesn't create subprocesses but *threads*.

```
def one(stdin):
    xyz = input("enter: ")
    print(xyz)

    time.sleep(1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    from multiprocessing.dummy import Process
    import time

    p1 = Process(target = one)
    p1.start()
```

since threads share the process, they also share standard input.

for real multiprocessing, I suggest that you collect interactive input from main process and pass it as argument.